# Why is this hex file different than the code programmed onto the device?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, programming, firmware, stm32f10x

I have a design using an [STM32F105](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/microcontrollers/stm32-32-bit-arm-cortex-mcus/stm32f1-series/stm32f105-107/stm32f105rc.html). My application written in C; using Eclipse and gcc. I have been using Eclipse (with OpenOCD and an [ST-LINK/V2](http://www.st.com/en/development-tools/st-link-v2.html) programmer) to write the firmware to the devices. Now I need to program many devices and am looking for a faster method.

The [ST-LINK Utility](http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stsw-link004.html) software seems to be a fine choice. You can point it to a .hex file and set it into "automatic mode". It then detects when a device is connected to the programmer and writes to it. Then you connect another device which will get automatically written. Very smooth.

So here's the problem: **It appears that the firmware written to the device by Eclipse is actually different than the Eclipse-generated hex file**.

This is what I'm seeing:

1. I program Device#1 via Eclipse. I remove the programmer, reset the device, and it works fine.
2. I find the Eclipse-generated .hex file (.../Debug/application.hex).
3. I program Device#2 using the ST_LINK Utility and this file. I remove the programmer. The **code doesn't run**, even after a device reset.
4. I use the ST-LINK Utility to read the (working) code directly from Device#1.
5. I use the ST-LINK Utility to program this code onto Device#2.  Now, **Device#2 works correctly**.

OK, so the generated .hex file must be wrong.  I can use the ST-LINK utility to compare the two hex files (from steps 2 and 4). It shows that the files are identical until the end:

*(click to zoom if you need to)*

[image: hexcomp]

---

Finally, my questions:

Why is the generated .hex file incorrect? Perhaps Eclipse uses gcc to create the hex, and then modifies it en route to the device? **How can I make Eclipse output a hex file that matches the code that it programs to an actual device?**

---

Note that I am building the "Debug" configuration. When Eclipse connects to the target device it programs the code and allows me to debug.  If I remove the debugger hardware, the device still functions.  That is, the code works fine without the debugger attached.

Comment: It looks like you've got a comms problem with dropped/inserted bits/bytes. It looks like a classic buffering/flow control problem, with the input buffer overflowing after 48 bytes have been transferred. Can you run the programmer at a slower speed? Also, make sure that you have a common ground throughout.

Comment: "Note that I am building the "Debug" configuration." - what happens if you build with 'release' configuration?

Comment: @Mick Thank you for that. I see the shifted values you're talking about.  However, the file that works is the one that I read from one device and wrote to another. The non-working file is straight from the IDE and has never been transmitted...

Comment: @BruceAbbott: I hadn't configured a 'release' configuration, so it took me a while to try this. Guess what; it worked! If you want to turn your comment into an answer I'd like to accept it. Apparently Eclipse programs 'debug' code (using the .elf file) in such a way that it can run without the debugger attached, even though the 'debug' hex file can't run on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Perhaps Eclipse uses gcc to create the hex, and then modifies it en
>   route to the device?

No, it's the other way round. When you compile a project in Eclipse,

1. individual files are compiled into `.o` object files
2. object files and libraries are linked into an `.elf` file
3. `objcopy` generates a `.hex` file from `.elf`
4. and finally the size is printed by `size`, but this last step is purely informational.

The debugger however works with the `.elf` from step 2, because it has symbols and other debugging aids in it, which are lost when converting to `.hex`. Therefore, I'd take a very close look at step 3, and perhaps at the `.elf` file too.

This is how step 3 should look like in the eclipse build console window

```
Finished building target: app.elf

Invoking: Cross ARM GNU Create Flash Image
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex "app.elf"  "app.hex"
Finished building: app.hex

Invoking: Cross ARM GNU Print Size
```

First, check if there are any warnings or other suspicious signs. Is it regenerated when you remove it, and build the project? And when you remove the `.elf`? Are the file timestamps correct? Try to repeat it from the command line. For that to work, you'll have to specify the full path to `arm-none-eabi-objcopy` in your toolchain, or include it in your `PATH`. Make sure that the toolchain path is properly set in eclipse, and there are no other versions of `objcopy` lying around, especially in your `PATH`.

You can examine the `.elf` with `arm-none-eabi-objdump`. List the "directory" with `-h`, it looks like this

```
app.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .isr_vector   0000013c  08008000  08008000  00008000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .text         0000b4cc  08008140  08008140  00008140  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  2 .rodata       0000b1c0  08013610  08013610  00013610  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  3 .ARM          00000008  0801e7d0  0801e7d0  0001e7d0  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .init_array   00000008  0801e7d8  0801e7d8  0001e7d8  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  5 .fini_array   00000004  0801e7e0  0801e7e0  0001e7e0  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  6 .data         00000a60  20000000  0801e7e4  00020000  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  7 .noinit       00000004  20000a60  0801f244  00020a60  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  8 .bss          0000cbf8  20000a68  0801f248  00020a68  2**3
                  ALLOC
```

Check the `LMA` and `Size` fields for each section. Is there an overlap? Dump the contents with `-s` and examine it around the problem address.